# I am automating a login script for perdormance teating in j meter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter, pkce

I want to make script using jmeter for performance testing of login page . The authorization type is code and code challenge method is sh256. How could I fetch code challenge code verifier and state or noance values daynamically.
The script is successfull for 1 single user but failing for multiple can any one help? Also I am using blazemeter to record script..

Answer (score 0):

The process of "fetching" dynamic values is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information on the topic in the Internet, i.e. [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)

The main steps are:

1. Use a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract a dynamic value from the response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Replace recorded hard-coded value with the JMeter Variable from the previous step

Comment: Hello dmitri i had already used post processors but few values like code vetifier and challenge need to be generated.. Which isn't possible by post processor